# Disable images in vb web browser

Tags: vb6

I am working with webbrowser control in vb6 but I want to disable images from webbrowser without going to settings in IE  if anyone could help me i will appreciate it thanks.

```
If checkbox1.value=1 then
'load images
else
'don't load images
End if
```

Like this

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
Private Sub webbrowser1_ProgressChange(ByVal Progress As Long, ByVal ProgressMax As Long)
    On Error Resume Next
      if checkbox1.value=1 then
           webbrowser1.Document.body.innerHTML = Replace(webbrowser1.Document.body.innerHTML, "<img", "<div ")
        Exit Sub
    End if
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Good code
Tnx for Share

webbrowser1.Document.body.innerHTML = Replace(web1.Document.body.innerHTML, "png", " ")
webbrowser1.Document.body.innerHTML = Replace(web1.Document.body.innerHTML, "jpg", " ")
webbrowser1.Document.body.innerHTML = Replace(web1.Document.body.innerHTML, "gif", " ")